# At what level did Xabi Alonso play Gaelic football?

Tags: trivia, gaelic-football

> Xabi Alonso is the only person to have both a Champions League medal and an All-Ireland medal.

I was told this wonderful bit of trivia, and would like to confirm it before using it in a quiz I’m writing, but am having difficulty doing so. He certainly has a Champions League medal, and he certainly did spend some time in Ireland in his youth (on a school exchange programme to improve his English), and did play some Gaelic football while here.

However, some sources say he just joined some local lads for an occasional kickabout, while others say he was in Ireland long enough to actually join a team properly, and some say that the team won an All Ireland final (one said it was a school team; another said it was not affiliated with a school and was just the underage team from Kells, Co. Meath). Most of this is just speculation on various messageboards. Is there any actual record of this?

(I suppose a supplemental question would be whether anyone *else* has both medals, but we’ll save that for a separate question.)

Comment: I am not sure who among all the users here will be an expert on Alonso's personal history and will be able to find any information that you can't find.

Comment: [this source](http://www.joe.ie/sport/five-famous-soccer-players-from-abroad-with-gaa-connections/485429) (that maybe you have seen) shows that Alonso play with local boys and the sentences "Maybe they should wear crash helmets" give me the impression he never play this sport to arrive at high level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xabi stayed with my family in Kells for 4 weeks and didn't win any medals. All he did was "kick-about" locally with friends of my son for fun.

Comment: Welcome to [sports.se]! It's great to have a first-hand source, but we like to have references backing up answers. Somebody else may come along, claim that Xabi stayed with them too and did win some medals ...

Answer (score -1):

Xabi Alonso hasn't got an all Ireland medal, rather he played during a summer camp whilst visiting Meath in Ireland when he was 16.

There are no Soccer players that have won the Champions League.

Cillian Sheridan played for Cavan's minor team and featured in the Champions League, however, has won neither.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. You have to add any references on what have you written to make your answer valid